# Getting the position of a text in a pdf

Tags: c#, itext

I am looking to acquire some "tabular" data from a pdf with iTextSharp in C#.
I am acquiring the pdf text via the `ReadLine()` method. However, I am trying to acquire some tabular data, when there is no data, a blank is left which does not appear as space or tabulation when doing the `ReadLine()`. Thus, I would need to acquire the position of those values to match them with the corresponding header.
I have investigated the `LocationTextStrategy` and `TextRegionEventFilter`, but I can't find a way to even get the position of the Line I am reading in the document or how I would be able to get the position of an element on that line.
If you have any idea of something that would be able to acquire this data that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including a sample PDF file, that illustrates what you are describing.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: What `ReadLine()` method do you mean? As far as I can see neither `PdfTextExtractor` nor `ITextExtractionStrategy` has such a method. Which iText version do you use? 5.x? 7.x?